# ¿Cuál es el origen de "chévere"?

Tags: etimología, hispanoamérica

Con frecuencia en Colombia (y supongo que en otros países) se oye **"chévere"** para decir que algo es bueno.

> Qué chévere, mañana es viernes y podremos rumbear.

El DRAE ya lo recoge:

> [**chévere**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=yoObiVH8wDXX2nBgsDjT)
>
> 1. adj. Ant., Ec., Hond., Méx., Pan. y Perú. Primoroso, gracioso, bonito, elegante, agradable.
> 2. adj. Á. Caribe, Bol., El Salv. y Hond. Estupendo, buenísimo, excelente.
> 3. adj. Col., Cuba, Pan., Perú, R. Dom. y Ven. Benévolo, indulgente. Un profesor chévere. Un examen chévere.
> 4. m. fest. P. Rico y Ven. petimetre.
> 5. adv. m. Ven. magníficamente (‖ muy bien).

Sin embargo, me pregunto: ¿cuál es el origen de esta palabra? Tiene un sonido francés, pero hasta la fecha no pude encontrar referencias.

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido ir a mirar la Wikipedia, a ver si había algún artículo sobre esta palabra y... uf. Bueno, la entradilla es un horror, pero luego hay una sección que ofrece algunas posibles etimologías interesantes. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A9vere#Origen

Comment: Idem para mi. He comprobado [_etimologias de Chile_](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?che.vere) y dice que es "de origen oscuro. Sólo sabemos que es reciente y que nació en Cuba". Las posibilidades que da creo que son más o menos las mismas que en la entrada de Wikipedia (1- esclavos africanos; 2- del francés [tanto por _cher_/querido como por el general Chevert]; 3- de Chevrolet, la marca de coches).

Comment: Tengo la impresión de que se trata de una palabra acuñada en Venezuela y que viene de la marca de coches Chevrolet, muy en boga en los años 50 y 60.

Comment: He encontrado una referencia en la litereatura Cubana; En 1931, Nicolás Guillén, poeta Cubano, escribió: ¨Chévere del navajazo,
se vuelve él mismo navaja:
Pica tajadas de luna,
mas la luna se le acaba;
pica tajadas de canto,
mas el canto se le acaba;
pica tajadas de sombra,
mas la sombra se le acaba,
y entonces pica que pica
carne de su negra mala.¨ Quizá ésta referencia sirva para comprobar los primeros usos de ésta palabra, ya que es obvio que en éste poema no se está utilizando con el significado actual.

Comment: Es importante agregar que fue Jose Luis Rodriguez "El Puma" quien popularizo la palabra por Latinoamerica.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cuando dicen que la palabra "chévere" posee un origen oscuro quizás lo digan metafóricamente. Y esto es debido a que la palabra chévere o 'chebere' existe y ha existido en el lenguaje 'efik' de la costa occidental de Africa. Durante más de dos siglos el vocablo es usado en estribillos cantados en la sociedad secreta 'abakua' de Cuba, conocidos generalmente como los 'nanigos'. El vocablo significa el bravo o el chulo.

Está muy asociado a la santería y a los esclavos negros que llegaron a las islas caribeñas.  Se dice que la palabra chévere (adaptada de los efik) es de origen cubano, y llega a Venezuela hacia comienzos de los años 40, proveniente del calabar (dialecto nigeriano) "sébede", que significa adornarse profusamente, vestirse con elegancia. Con el paso de los años la palabra fue tomando la figura y fuerza de todo lo relacionado a bueno, agradable, estupendo, excelente, maravilloso, "guay", etc.

Comment: Fantástica respuesta. ¡Muchas gracias por ella y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se]!

Answer (score 0):

La palabra CHEVERE es de origen VENEZOLANO, tienes sus orígenes en el siglo 20 en la zona central del país como Caracas, La Victoria, Maracay, Valencia y Pto. cabello. Fue conjugada para referirse a las noCHE VEnezolana de buenas RElaciones, osea buenas fiestas, sitios, personas y fines de semana.

Comment: ¡Curioso! Veo referencias al respecto, pero ninguna definitiva. ¿Alguien sabe más sobre el tema?

Answer (score 0):

Tengo 72 años de edad y desde que tengo uso de razón digo esta palabra porque en mi país Colombia en la región caribe, principalmente en Barranquilla, es muy común y mis antepasados la decían y por eso las generaciones en generación se aprende. Es expresar que es bueno, bonito, hermoso, mejor dicho todo lo bueno.

Comment: ¡Chévere!  Pero sigo con la duda, ¿aceptas la explicación de @Damalux o propones otra?

Answer (score 0):

Nada definitivo pero [este articulo](https://m.elpais.com.co/entretenimiento/cultura/chevere-de-donde-sale-esa-palabra.html) sobre el posible origen de **chévere** está interesante.

Viene a decir que los esclavos africanos que llegaron a Cuba se trajeron una lengua secreta de una sociedad secreta africana, los abakuá, en la que "chévere" significaba "valiente, maravilloso, excelente". Este lenguaje secreto se usaba a veces en canciones cubanas a principios del s. XX y de ahí supuestamente pasó **chévere** al lenguaje español con el significado actual. Cosa que el autor descubrió hablando con personas mayores que le contaron la historia.

Answer (score 0):

Chévere se usó en un anuncio publicitario (jingle) de la Chevrolet a finales de los 50 y entrados los 60, que decía “¡Qué chevere (bis) es mi Chevrolet”. Cuyo autor fue el conocido publicista Alfredo Cortina. La difusión por radio fue espectacular y desde entonces se usa en Venezuela para referirse a algo muy bueno o agradable.

Comment: Muy interesante esta respuesta.  ¿Se puede encontrar una referencia que compruebe esto?